# OTRS. How I can create ticket for unregister customers?

Tags: otrs

I use OTRS and not all clients want register in this system. In OTRS GUI I use a page (example.com/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketEmail) for create ticket by email. 
Last time I begin use OTRS API for [creating ticket](http://otrs.github.io/doc/api/otrs/stable/Perl/Kernel/GenericInterface/Operation/Ticket/TicketCreate.pm.html), but I don`t understood how use this method for unregister users. 
[Screen the form for creating ticket by email](https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/532646/s4tm6eoiafpeopvhokqg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the TicketCreate operation mandates having an existing customer user in OTRS. You could modify the TicketCreate operation (specified in `Kernel/GenericInterface/Operation/Ticket/TicketCreate.pm`) to not require this; or you could create a new operation where you could register your customers if needed.

Comment: I right understand that from external service I can run only this methods ( SessionCreate, TicketCreate, TicketGet, TicketSearch, TicketUpdate). I not found a manual for using other methods from OTRS API. thanks.